# How to print dict string

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to print my string from a raw input with brackets.

Here is my code.

```
words = (raw_input('Please enter a string:  '))

names = list(words)
print names
```

I'm getting this:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

I only need like this:

```
[Hello]
```

Comment: What is the expected output if the user types more than one word? For example, `Hello how are you doing`?

Comment: Everything needs to be in a brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need `list` , just use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or `%s` :

```
words = raw_input('Please enter a string: ')

names = '[{}]'.format(words) # or '[%s]'%words
print names
```

and if the user write more than one word you can first split the input and print it (Note that you need to be sure that there are space between them ):

```
print words.split()
```

Answer (score 2):

`words` is a string and can be considered as a list of characters.
`list(words)` changes the string into a list of it's characters.

If what you want is a list with only one element (the string), make a list with that element:

```
>>> words = "This is a Test."
>>> names = [words]
>>> print names
['This is a Test.']
```

If what you want is a list of every words in the string, split the string:

```
>>> words = "This is a Test."
>>> names = words.split()
>>> print names
['This', 'is', 'a', 'Test.']
```

`.split()` splits the string at every space to make a list of strings.

EDIT: I just understood you wanted the string printed between brackets and without the quotes, Kasra's format string is good then.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

> words = (raw_input('Please enter a string:  '))
>
> names = []
>
> names.append(words)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> words = []
>>> words.append(raw_input('enter the code: '))
enter the code: vis
>>> words
['vis']
```

Comment: How would you remove the tildes.